# Appending id within jQuery function call?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a method to append #dimensionName_ inside handleResults() with current_index of add_filter_Form?

I have the following code:

```
this.add_filter_form = function (name, value, status) {
                    form_count++;
                    current_index++;
                    form_status[current_index] = status;

                    $("#_IWID_Filters_included").append("<div id='filter_" + current_index + "'>" +
                        "Filter name: <select id = 'dimensionName_" + current_index + "'></select>" +
                        "Filter value: <select id ='dimensionId_" + current_index + "'></select>" +
                        "<button type='button' id='remove_btn_" + current_index + "' onclick='filter_forms.remove_filter_form(" + current_index + ")' style='margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 5px;'>Remove filter</button>" +
                        "</div>");
                }

function handleResults(responseObj) 
            {
                //Populates every dimensionName_[current_index] with names:
                $("#dimensionName_").html(responseObj.DimensionListItem.map(function(item) 
                {
                    return $('<option>').text(item.dimensionDisplayName)[0];
                }));
            }
```

Im looking for something along the effects of:

```
$("#'dimensionName_ + current_index'")
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you need or post a simple example with dummy values.

Comment: I updated the question; given is what I want but that code will obviously not work :/

Comment: therefore we should need to know in what order those functions are being called

Comment: did you try `$("#dimensionName_ "+current_index)`

Comment: add_filter_form will be called first so that the <select> tags are appended into the form. Once created, handleResults() will populate every created <select id = dimensionName_[current_index]> based on how many there are.

Comment: What about adding a particular empty css class to all of these elements and selecting all of them by that class instead of their ID, leaving the rest up to jQuery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've understood you are setting the current_index via add_filter and need this value asynchronously inside handleResults. Therefor, you need to make this variable globally available:

```
var current_index = 0;

this.add_filter_form = ...

function handleResults(responseObj){
  $("#dimensionName_" + current_index).html();
}
```

Comment: Problem with global vars is always the initialization and resetting!

Comment: you can do this in an anonymous function closure, no problem at all

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass the current index variable to the handleResults function. you also need to call that function in the scope of the current_index variable or save a copy in the objects scope from within an other function. so you could use this.current_index

```
function handleResults(responseObj, current_index) {...
```

you need to concatenate the strings. just use + sign for that.

```
$("#dimensionName_"+current_index)...
```